# at top of python program, a command "import csv" "is not accessed" where to find it

Tags: csv, import

import csv
fails, alert "csv.py" is not accessed
yes, there is no file of that name in my current working directory.

Where can I locate a copy of csv.py to use in my current project.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse  #this command works 
import obo  #this command works because I have obo.py in my directory
import csv   # csv is underlines with white dots, csv is not accessed
```

where do I seek csv.ph?
running windows Visual Studio version 1.73.1

Answer (score 0):

Newbie error. The warning from Visual Studio only meant that I imported a module but didn't use it in the program.